Ubuntu 24.04 has changed the way additional hostnames are treated in /etc/hosts, how can I restore the 20.04 behavior?
I have a number of local test hosts named in /etc/hosts thus:
127.0.0.1 localhost local-a local-b remote1 remote1-a local-sfbay remote2 remote2-a roger1

When I migrated to 24.04, one old, but still regularly used, application (old_app) that was working correctly with 20.04 using this configuration now only works when launched with the host specified as localhost. So in 22.04 ~$ old_app remote1 works but in 24.04 it hangs. ~$ old_app localhost works in both releases.
I don't have access to the internal workings of old_app. Ping to the additional hosts works fine in both releases and I can ssh to the hosts without a problem in both releases.
My hostname resolution order is the same on both 20.04 and 24.04.
I currently still have access to the 20.04 working system but it is scheduled for retirement.
It is not an area I know much about but I did stop the systemd-resolved daemon and try again. It made no difference. The DNS resolution order appeared to be file first which suggests to me it will start with /etc/hosts. Everything else seems to work find for these hosts - I can ping them, ssh to them, rsync between them.

It is not an area I know much about but I did stop the systemd-resolved daemon and try again. It made no difference. The DNS resolution order appeared to be file first which suggests to me it will start with /etc/hosts. Everything else seems to work find for these hosts - I can ping them, ssh to them, rsync between them...

"hangs" seems an odd outcome if the issue is hostname resolution - it should either succeed or fail. Does old_app 127.0.0.1 work? What is the output of getent hosts remote1 localhost?

127.0.0.2       remote1.localdomain local-a local-b remote1 remote1-a local-sfbay remote2 remote2-a roger1
127.0.0.1       localhost
